# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maraboupy.MarabouCore'

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, kaggle

I would like to use the maraboupy python package on a Kaggle notebook. I have tried this:

```
!git clone https://github.com/NeuralNetworkVerification/Marabou.git
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/kaggle/working/Marabou')
```

But when I try the following code, I get

> 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maraboupy.MarabouCore'

```
from maraboupy import Marabou
```

[Here](https://neuralnetworkverification.github.io/Marabou/Setup/0_Installation.html) is the installation guide

Based on the installation guide, I have tried the following commands:

```
mkdir build 
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON
cmake --build .
```

I got this:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:239 (target_include_directories): Cannot specify include directories for imported target "openblas".
```

Help me to install maraboupy on Kaggle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details, but I've got maraboupy working in a different set-up.

From the CMake Error it seems that you are running the installation commands in `'/kaggle/working'` if so, try running the commands in `'/kaggle/working/Marabou'` this is where my CMakeLists.txt is at least.

Another difference I can spot is that I added Marabou to path as well, don't know if that is important. In your case I suppose this would be:

```
!git clone https://github.com/NeuralNetworkVerification/Marabou.git
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/kaggle/working/Marabou/maraboupy')
sys.path.insert(2, '/kaggle/working/Marabou')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used `/kaggle/working/Marabou` and it was working. However, I have got another error. I have updated the question. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please also explain why did you use the same path insert two times?

Comment: Oops, the duplicate line was a mistake. As for the new error message I have no idea. You could perhaps add the relevant lines in CMakeLists.txt and what values `${OPEN_BLAS_DIR}` and `${OPEN_BLAS_LIB}` have (if they seem relevant) in the question or ask a new question. If you're lucky someone that has more experience with cmake can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it was helpful.